# Why does logical not character (¬) appear in HTTP GET query string

Tags: http, url, html-entities

The following HTML demonstrates my issue - when I mouseover the link or click it, `&not` becomes %AC in Chrome and ¬ in Firefox, making the query nonsensical. This behavior doesn't make sense to me and I haven't found it described in any documentation, although other than an RFC about URLs I don't really know where to look.

```html
<html>
<body>
<p><a href="http://localhost/?truth=falsehood&not_broken=broken">foo</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

The context is that I have some javascript that generates HTTP GET parameters to appear in link urls based on responses from the server. If the field of one of these parameters starts with `not_` so that `&not_` appears in the query string, both Chrome and Firefox seem to convert the `&not` to ¬ (the symbol for 'not' in mathematical formal logic) if I inspect the URL with dev tools and then, in Chrome's case, into something involving %AC when I click on the link, making it into nonsense. Presumably this is because of the HTML entity `&not;` which codes for that symbol (U+00AC), but the query string does not have a semicolon in it.

My question is why the browser replaces `&not` with this character inside an `href` attribute where `&` has a different special meaning even though there is no semicolon, and if there is any better way to mitigate this than avoiding HTML entity names in query strings.

Comment: Browsers for decades have allowed nonstandard HTML whenever they can make a half-reasonable guess (which Chrome obviously judged this one to be), because nearly all HTML on the World Wide Web is written by people who don't obey any standards and usually don't even know there are standards; they just do whatever they saw somewhere, or simply guess. Purists tried to enforce standards with HTML4/XHTML and it was laughed out of the room. A browser that rejected all bad HTML would be rated by users as worthless, and discarded quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, an ampersand character in an HTML attribute needs to be escaped as `&amp;`.

You can get away without it if it's use is unambiguous, but this is not the case here.

Comment: I wasn't aware you needed to (or even could) replace & with &amp; inside attributes as well, although that makes sense to me now. Interestingly the living standard suggests that for legacy reasons (presumably this use case) an entity inside an attribute that is missing a semicolon and followed by = or an alphanumeric character should not be parsed: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#named-character-reference-state. But apparently that behavior is inconsistent across browsers.